# why my script is not working on ajax document?

Tags: javascript, ajax

My js code is not working on document loaded by ajax.

Below is my html-js structure.

1. index.html
2. abc.js included in index.html
3. fine.html inside index.html (loaded by ajax_abc.js)

And if I define some variable(refer to element in fine.html), that variable becomes null.

For example,

**index.html:**

```
<script src="abc.js"></script>
```

**abc.js:**

```
ajax load document sententes;
var a = document.getElementById('asdf'); // asdf is located in fine.html
```

**browser console:**

```
a; // result: null

a = document.getElementById('asdf');
a; // result: not null
```

I think that's because when abc.js was loaded, fine.html wasn't existed.

Thay's why abc.js is not working on fine.html(ajax document).

I putted abc.js in the bottom of fine.html, but that wasn't effect.

How can I make my script works on ajax document?

**ajax code inside abc.js:**

```
var xhr;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function xhrDocOpen(doc){
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            document.getElementById('bodyFrame').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',doc,true);
    xhr.send();
}
    xhrDocOpen('introOrgan.html');
```

Comment: The problem probably depends on where you put your ```<script src="abc.js"></script>``` inside your html code. Can you complete your html code to at least show us where are the ```<head>```, the ```<body>``` and the ```asdf``` element ?

Comment: I put external script code on the bottom of the document, right above the </body>.. and it works fine with index.html. shows functional problem only with ajax document. So I think the place is not the reason..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct scope for `document`.

This line:

`var a = document.getElementById('asdf');`

is failing because `document` is for index.html, not fine.html.

First, you need to wait until fine.html is loaded.

Try this instead, it waits until the content is loaded before assigning `a` to the element that was injected from fine.html:

```
var a;
var xhr;
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
function xhrDocOpen(doc){
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            // load content from fine.html into DOM
            document.getElementById('bodyFrame').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;

            // search DOM after fine.html content loaded
            a = document.getElementById('asdf');
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET',doc,true);
    xhr.send();
}
    xhrDocOpen('introOrgan.html');
```

Comment: you are right. than what kind of keyword need to replace document?

Comment: I updated the code above. At first I thought you were using an IFRAME but I misunderstood. Your code was failing because you were assigning `a` before the content from fine.html was loaded. Then in your console you assigned it and it was no longer null, because by then the content had been loaded (timing issue).

Comment: Thanks, but is that only way to approach from outside script to elements of ajax document?